# INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider)

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I Have Been working on AWS EC2, i have installed all the required Dependencies for it Like java and Kafka version. But when I run the zookeeper on the EC2 machine this gives me the following error. Can Somebody tells me whats the matter? Is this error is about the timeout value? Or any Ip address probelem?

`

```
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,465] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.slotDuration = 15 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,465] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.maxDepth = 6 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,466] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.initialDelay = 5 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,467] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.delay = 5 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,468] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.enabled = false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,472] INFO The max bytes for all large requests are set to 104857600 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,473] INFO The large request threshold is set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,473] INFO Created server with tickTime 3000 minSessionTimeout 6000 maxSessionTimeout 60000 clientPortListenBacklog -1 datadir /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 snapdir /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,495] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,496] WARN maxCnxns is not configured, using default value 0. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,502] INFO Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 1 selector thread(s), 2 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,508] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,514] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:78)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:676)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:158)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:112)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:67)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:140)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:90)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,521] INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider)
[2023-10-08 18:42:43,529] ERROR Exiting JVM with code 1 (org.apache.zookeeper.util.ServiceUtils)
```

Comment: 1. Something is running on that port already... 2. Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper. 3. Use MSK so you don't need to use EC2 and may misconfigure Kafka yourself